# Get left and top of flexbox positioned element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

When elements are laid out using flexbox, I'd like to know what their top and left is relative to the window.

Is this possible?

Using `window.getComputedStyle` returns `auto` for both `top` and `left` properties.

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell')

cells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const cell = event.target;
    const left = getComputedStyle(cell).left;
    const top = getComputedStyle(cell).top;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 'Left: ' + left + ' - Top: ' + top;
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .row {
  display: flex;
}

:root {
  --cell-size: 20px;
}

.container .row .cell {
  width: var(--cell-size);
  height: var(--cell-size);
  background-color: steelblue;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: calc(var(--cell-size) / 4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS Animation demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Click a flex child to see its computed top and left</div>
    <div id="display">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You won't be able to get the computed style because left and top are only computed when the element is absolute positioned.

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element - covers the getting left and top offsets, but not the condition of "only flex elements".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `.offsetLeft` and `.offsetTop`:

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell')

cells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const cell = event.target;
    const left = cell.offsetLeft;
    const top = cell.offsetTop;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 'Left: ' + left + ' - Top: ' + top;
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .row {
  display: flex;
}

:root {
  --cell-size: 20px;
}

.container .row .cell {
  width: var(--cell-size);
  height: var(--cell-size);
  background-color: steelblue;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: calc(var(--cell-size) / 4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS Animation demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Click a flex child to see its computed top and left</div>
    <div id="display">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are these values definitely right? If I add a div with `position: absolute` and a top and left of the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`  of one of the flexbox children, they don't *quite* line up!

Comment: My bad: needed to take the margins into account!